# Rails activerecords with nested includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class BusinessProcess < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos
end

class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :row
end

class Row < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

How can I count the number of `rows` in a `BusinessProcess` that has rows on a specific `user`?

Something like:

`@businessProcess.todos.includes(XXX).where(users.id=?,1).count`

Comment: Could you please add the code of the ActiveRecord classes? At least the associations. By the way *@businessProcess* is not very Rubyish.

Comment: I've been looking at your problem. Can you clarify one thing? In `Row`, you have `has_many :users`. This implies, I think, that `User` should have a `belongs_to :row`. Which seems, then, like a `User` can have only one `Row`. Is this correct? It seems odd, as a `User` would presumably have many Rows, in which case you would need a many-to-many join model. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@businessProcess.todos.includes(:row => :users).where("users.id=?",1).count

Comment: If you just want to count the number of rows in a BusinessProcess, that is not a apropriate solution, since you instantiate all Todo objects, Row objects and User objects as well. That is slow.

Comment: Rows in this case is a model and not a normal row. What I want is to count the rows belongs to BusinessProcess through todo. I see no other way around it. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

According to your associations, I'd rather go with just joining the tables like:

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :row
  has_many: users, through: :row

  scope :by_user_id, ->(user_id) { 
    joins(:users).where("users.id = ?", user_id)
  }
end
```

and then:

```
@business_process.todos.by_user_id(1).count
```

Maybe you also could think of moving the *where* condition into a scope of *Row*, but that is more a responsibility thingie.
You also could read about ARel as an alternative: [The N+1 problem and ARel](http://www.chrisrolle.com/blog/the-n-1-problem-and-arel).